# Flash game with android support

Tags: android, flash, actionscript-3

I'm making a flash game this week, it needs to be compatable with both PC browsers and Android devices.

I have no problem making two slightly different versions of the game, one optimized for PC and the other optimized for mobile devices. I'm just wondering if there's anything in particular that I should keep in-mind when I'm building the first PC edition of the game, I don't want it to be too difficult to port the game over to android.

One thing that I'm concerned about is the screen size/stage size, should I have the game adjust it's self to fill the whole client area (like a youtube video in full screen) with a dynamic width and height?

Is there anything else that I should be aware of before I start on this? Like specific flaws in the android deployment of flash.

Thanks for your advice on this, it's much appreciated.

Comment: Well, i recommend you to use the Device Central with different resolutions and Screen resolutions, cause with Ipad for example rendering quality is superior than some Android devices. Need to be sure about yours targetted devices.

Comment: @papachan - thanks for the advice, I took a look at some Device Central videos earlier and looks worthwhile. I'll also be using the emulator to test with, I don't have an android phone but I did manage to get an hp touchpad (just waiting for the android port).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were more number of restrictions when i started developing flash apps for android.

1. We need the device's processor at least 1GHz [This i am not aware of current situation , coz i am a little busy with xCode]
2. Screen resolution always plays more role in troubling you. For this instead of using screen size as reference , use the aspect ratio. Use flash.capabilities class's screenResolutionX and screenResolutionY and make your game objects resize them accordingly